# GTK+ compile in Bloodshed Dev-C++ compiler error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gtk

I'm trying to compile a C program using GTK+ in bloodshed Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

I've added all the include files in the compiler options plus all compiler options, but I get the following error:

Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Makefile.win" all
gcc.exe main.o  -o "MyCProject.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0  -lcairo -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lfreetype -lzdll -lfontconfig -lpng13 -lpangocairo-1.0

C:\Dev-Cpp\Bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: **cannot find -lintl**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make.exe: *** [MyCProject.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated

Can someone help me with what '-lintl' is and if it's a package missing or some file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibIntl

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm

You can get devpak from [HERE](http://devpaks.org/details.php?devpak=25)

Aside:

I don't think Dev-C++ has been updated in years. Have you considered moving to [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: Thanks man, now it gives me the same error for -lzdll, where do I get that?

Comment: Can you use it to compile C and GTK+?

Comment: Erm same site http://devpaks.org/details.php?devpak=154
If you go to the site http://devpaks.org there are many packages available

Comment: Yes, all these IDEs can use MingW as the compiler, these are just fancy frontends to make it easier to develop. you can use devpaks with code::blocks too